# Parse date from the past. 

Tags: php, html, function

So lets say I have a bunch of dates in the format of `m/d/y`. So say our date is 1/1/2001, I want it to display `January 1st, 2001`.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of strtotime()

```
$original = '1/1/2001';
echo date("F jS, Y", strtotime($original));
```

Also don't forget about php's DateTime object, which I've finally been using lately.

```
$original = '1/1/2001';
$Date = new DateTime($original);
echo $Date->format("F jS, Y");
```

Answer (score 1):

[`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) accepts an optional timestamp as second argument:

```
echo date("F jS, Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2001));

// prints: January 1st, 2001
```

To supply `mktime` with the right arguments, take a look at [`strptime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php).

Comment: but lets say i have my dates in another format... ex:1/1/2001.